# Question on Xreg - potential double accounting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I am using the `auto.arima()` function with xreg feature to forecast total number of helpdesk calls.

So, input to the time series is total number of calls and input to xreg is number of devices (also using time series to forecast the total number of devices in the future).

Since the total number of calls increases when the number of devices increase, and the historical data for total number of calls already factors in the increase in devices, will there be double accounting if I still use total number of devices as additional predictor?

Comment: Since you have two series, why not using multivariate model like [VAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression)?

Answer (score 1):

No, there won't be double accounting.

There are several ways of combining exogenous regressors with ARIMA models.  One is ARIMAX modeling, another is transfer function modeling (as in the confusingly-named`arimax` function in the TSA package), and a third is the approach used in `auto.arima`, which fits a regression with ARMA errors.  Double accounting won't occur with any of these approaches.

With the transfer function model, all the parameters are jointly estimated, so the trend will be captured by whatever mix of time series and exogenous variable parameters does the best job.

With `auto.arima`, if the regression captures a trend, there won't be a trend left in the errors for the ARMA model to capture.

For a nice very high level overview of time series models approaches with some references to R, albeit a little out of date, check out https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/.